# Blockchain development under 200GB?

Tags: polkadot, blockchain, general

I'm trying to make meaningful code contributions to Substrate/Polkadot ecosystem in the hopes of becoming a Blockchain developer one day. I tried the Substrate approach and discovered that it takes more than 100GB (around 115GB and possibly higher) of storage to have Substrate on my computer. I thought it's quite a lot and decided to try Polkadot instead, which takes about 80GB. But then I discovered that Polkadot apparently requires Substrate as a dependency, which means I would need around 200GB of storage to contribute to Polkadot.

So now I'm considering having only Substrate without Polkadot. 115GB is a lot, but I guess it's tolerable. This whole software development endeavor must never exceed 200GB in total under any circumstances (and preferably not get too close to 200GB, because I'd like to leave some margins for swap memory), because otherwise I would run out of space on my computer.

I'm worried that in addition to 115GB of substrate, that I might need additional dependencies (or extra types of builds) that would put the total storage usage above 200GB.

Is there any feasible way for me to contribute to Polkadot/Substrate software, without occupying more than 200GB of storage, in a way that helps me develop the skills I need to become a blockchain developer?

Comment: What kind of storage are you referring to? Github repository size? On-chain data?

Comment: computer storage

Comment: when I do things like `git clone [repository]` and then run `cargo build` and `cargo test`, it ends up taking ridiculous amount of space on my computer